# Using Invoke-SQL query with Foreach loop

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a list of instances I have imported into the

$SQLServerList

I want to have them look for the databases on each instance.

```
foreach ($server in $SQLServerList ){
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "use master select name, database_id, create_date, recovery_model_desc from sys.databases"  -ServerInstance $server
}
```

however this won't run what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error/output, if any, are you getting? And can you share the code that populates $SQLServerList? Thanks.

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance
At M:\IT\IT Teams\Database Support Team\Powershell Scripts\SQL Inventory 2\SQL Server Inventory.ps1:18 char:24
+ ... _database = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "use master select name, database_id ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotGetServerInstance,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: Looks like $SQLServerList doesn't contain quite what you think it does - how is it populated?

Comment: Your list of Server instances seem to be empty. Have you checked what `$SQLServerList` contain?

Comment: I imported it from CSV.... when i run the $SQLServerList there is about 100 rows all server names.

Comment: Please show the code, but it'll probably be something like changing $server to $server.name

Comment: @GarethLyons it was $SQLServerList.Server... BINGO! thanks man! now how do i give you the points?

Comment: Cool, I'll write up an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a CSV file with column 'Server' containing the server names, using

`$SQLServerList = import-csv servers.csv`

on the file will return an object with NoteProperty `'Server'`. (Imagine the csv has multiple columns, you need a way to identify which one you're accessing, and the `$SQLServerList` object will contain a property for each column).

When using this in `foreach ($server in $SQLServerList)` , `$SQLServerList` and `$server` represent the whole object, which doesn't make much sense when passed to `invoke-sqlcmd`, so `$Server.Server` is required.

Alternatively, `$SQLServerList = (import-csv servers.csv).Server` returns a string array and should be usable directly in `foreach ($server in $SQLServerList)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below it should make it easier to troubleshoot your error.. See if the count matches what you have in the CSV file. You can also list it out to view the content of the CSV.. plus changed the database in use from inside the script to the Parameter -Database.

```
$inputfile = "C:\Databases\JUSTCREATED.csv"


[Array]$SQLServerList = get-content -Path $inputfile

$SQLServerList.count

foreach ($server in $SQLServerList ){


    Write-Output $server
    try{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query " select name, database_id, create_date, recovery_model_desc from sys.databases"  -ServerInstance $server -Database master
        }
        catch 
        {

        Write-Output $_.Exception.Message


        }

}
```